# CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED in Google Colab, dlib face detection project

Tags: google-colaboratory, dlib

I was trying out dlib‘s deep learning-based face detection MMOD, and it worked perfectly fine without any errors. After the weekend, I rerun my google colab, and I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Error while calling cudnnConvolutionBiasActivationForward( context(), &alpha1, descriptor(data), data.device(), (const cudnnFilterDescriptor_t)filter_handle, filters.device(), (const cudnnConvolutionDescriptor_t)conv_handle, (cudnnConvolutionFwdAlgo_t)forward_algo, forward_workspace, forward_workspace_size_in_bytes, &alpha2, out_desc, out, descriptor(biases), biases.device(), identity_activation_descriptor(), out_desc, out) in file /tmp/pip-install-fdw8qrx_/dlib_e3176ea453c4478d8dbecc372b81297e/dlib/cuda/cudnn_dlibapi.cpp:1237. code: 9, reason: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

literally same code previously saved in GitHub, and now in google colab

[image: literally same code previously saved in GitHub, and now in google colab]

Any ideas about what could have happened over the weekend, and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Colaboratory runs on a range of different hardware and default software versions. The instance you got now is probably differently provisioned from what you got last week

Comment: I see... So what do you think would be the best way to work around this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I can't offer you any solution. Depending on time of day, location, and load, you can wind up on hardware in different data centres and those can have different feature sets and software stack versions on them.

Comment: I see... Thank you for the explanation. I suspected it might be something like that, but wanted to make sure... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after I tried EVERYTHING I could come up with (trying the code on a different machine, on a different platform, check if there were any library updates), I went through my github committed version, and realized, that the dlib library was updated, but not announced anywhere...

So yeah, note for the future self: always include the .**version** afterimporting the tools, might save DAYS of trying to figure out what on earth happened

Comment: I had the same problem. Solved downgrading dlib:
`!pip install dlib==19.22.1`

Comment: Be aware that `!pip install dlib==19.22.1` took about 9 minutes to complete the installation.